# Differences between smart-home-nodejs and actions-on-google-nodejs

Tags: actions-on-google, google-smart-home

What's the different between smart-home-nodejs (https://github.com/actions-on-google/smart-home-nodejs) and actions-on-google-nodejs (https://github.com/actions-on-google/actions-on-google-nodejs) handlers for Smart Home intents?
Which method should I use to create a Smart Home Application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `actions-on-google-nodejs` is a library for Node.js which simplifies the work you need to take in developing actions, including smart home actions.

The `smart-home-nodejs` is a sample project showing you one way to get started quickly with the smart home vertical. It does not use the `actions-on-google` library, as it was put together before the library supported smart home, and that's an outstanding feature request.

For an example of smart home that does use the library, you can check out the [smart home codelab](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/smarthome-washer).

Comment: Thank you @Nick! Then I'll use the `actions-on-google` library for smart home!